# How can i overload operator as virtual

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, virtual

I have a simple inheritance structure:

- Base <- Derived1
- Base <- Derived2

I want to overload << and >> operators to input and print data in objects `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes as a reference to `Base` class.

Can I declare some kind of virtual functions? Like this :

```
virtual std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& obj) = 0;
virtual std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Base& obj) = 0;
```

in my `Base` class, and override them in `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes?

I want to do some things like that:

```
std::vector<Base&> a;
... push reference to Derived1 and Derived2 objects ...
for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i) std::cin >> (*i);
for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i) std::cout << (*i);
```

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& obj) = 0;` overloads `operator <<` of `std::ostream` class, not of `Base` class. If you have this in mind, the answer will become clear.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, i know it. but i still want to get overloading versions of that operators, that i can call in Base class reference

Comment: Well, it looks okay. Have you tried it? Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only member functions can be virtual, but these `operator<<` and `operator>>` cannot be member functions of your class because their first argument is a stream, not the class that overloads these operators.

You can overload `operator<<` and `operator>>` adaptor functions for your class, which forward the call into the corresponding virtual functions of your class (the 2nd argument):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual std::ostream& output(std::ostream&) const = 0;
    virtual std::istream& input(std::istream&) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& obj) { return obj.output(os); }
inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Base& obj) { return obj.input(is); }
```

Comment: Wow! Its very beautiful.. THANKS

Comment: That is the technique I use, although I call them `print` and `input`.  (_sniff_  I smell BASIC.)  I also make binary `write` and `read`, and diagnostic `debug`.