# c++ multiple classes with identical methods which use 'this' in

Tags: c++, oop

i need an advice with oop.
So basically I have several classes which have identical methods but in this methods `this` keyword is being used.

I tried with inheritance and i found i can access derived class’s `this` like so:
`static_cast<derived *>(this)`, but as I understand that considered as a bad practice. Here is the code with derivation:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
    void add(string filename) {
        ofstream file;
        file.open(filename, ios::app);
        file.write((char*)static_cast<T*>(this), sizeof(*static_cast<T*>(this)));
        file.close();
    }
};

class Product : public Base<Product> {
public:
    char id[11];
    char name[50];
    char price[9];
    char stock[9];
};
```

Here is the class:

```
class Product {
public:
    char id[11];
    char name[50];
    char price[9];
    char stock[9];

public:
    void add(string filename) {
        ofstream file;
        file.open(filename, ios::app);
        file.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
        file.close();
    }
};
```

I have several other classes like this and all of them has identical `add()` method. And i want to know what is the best way to do this without code duplication or is it better with code duplication in terms of readablity and stuff like that?

Comment: If you understand that casts are sometimes a bad practice, what's your opinion on the C-style cast in `(char*)this`? BTW: There's no derivation in your code even, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: Hi @UlrichEckhardt, i recently learned that casting is a bad practice and i didn't know that when i'm writing the peice of code that you've mentioned. Thank you for pointing out i'll fix that too.

Comment: As for derivation, i'm just wondering what is the best practise in a situation where you have identical methods in multiple classes but `this` keyword is being used in them.

Comment: The code provided does not use a `static_cast` in the manner for which the question asks about.  I suspect the problem is that the `add` function is doing *two* things, but really should be doing *one* thing.  Refactoring & decomposing that method into two separate methods, and then the writing method using a virtual member function will probably take care of the problem and be the solution to the question.

Comment: `file.write((char*)static_cast<T*>(this), sizeof(*static_cast<T*>(this)));` no no no no!!! NO!!! That is wrong on so many levels. Please tell us what is your intention, what you hope that does and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Writing an object out as a raw blob requires `static_assert(std::is_trivial<Product>::value);` and `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Product>::value);`, which passes in the code given, but may easily & inadvertently fail as the code evolves.  Worth adding the asserts, or better yet not writing as a raw blob (but that's your call).

Comment: 20y ago, when I was first taught C++, this was all achieved by overloading the >> and << operators. Let each class decide how to serialise its state. However things may have evolved since then.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441920/how-can-i-overload-operator-as-virtual

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is called serialization. You may need a library like [libnop](https://github.com/google/libnop). Google 'C++ serialization library' for other options.